# Do FileStream buffer support random writes without auto flush?

Tags: .net, filestream

I have a FileStream of 10 MB and I'm writing random positions (about 2 kB in total) with a buffer of 4 kB. Will the stream only write to the buffer and only write to disk when flushing? Or does this only apply when writing in total a sequential range less than the buffer size? Do I need to set the buffer size to 10 MB to be sure that flush never is done automatically?

What I'm trying to do is to allow multiple readers on a file on disk and at the same time allow one writer to make changes without affecting the readers, ie writing only to a memory buffer, and then only write lock when flushing the changes to disk.

Comment: any time you change position, [the buffers are flushed](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.Windows.cs#L522-L538) (note: `Position` calls `Seek()`); what is it that you want to do? would `MemoryMappedFile` perhaps be a better option? (note: that also writes to disk - it is, fundamentally, a *memory mapped file* - but it has different bahavior); what is the thing you're trying to avoid here? If you don't want changes going to disk, using a `FileStream` seems a bad idea...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid locking readers while writing (except when flushing) -- but I realize I probably gain very little with that. I would be even better if I could have completely lockfree readers, ie writing to a new file and perhaps overlaying it with the old somehow. I can't copy the old file entirely and replace it atomically, I mean I could but that would be even worse performance I think.